# Finding the domain and range of $f(x)=\frac{2e^x}{1+e^x}$, and of $f^{-1}(x)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

> What is the domain and range of :
> $$ f(x) = \frac{2e^x}{1+e^x} $$
> and the domain and range of :
> $$ f^{-1}(x)$$

I've already found $$ f^{-1}(x) = \ln\left(\frac {x}{2-x}\right) $$

I'm looking for the process necessary to find its domain and range. Many thanks.

Comment: Some things to think about: If $f$ is invertible, then the domain and range will swap between $f$ and $f^{-1}$.  Since you have both formulas for $f$ and $f^{-1}$ you could find the domain and range for either, and it would tell you what you need for both.

Answer (score 2):

*Little lemma:* $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}:$ $$ 0<\frac{2}{1+e^x} < 2$$
*Proof:*
We know that $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}:$ $$ 0< e^x <\infty$$
Using this, we observe
$$ \frac{2}{1+e^x} < \frac{2}{1 + 0} = 2 \\ \frac{2}{1+e^x} > \frac{2}{1+\infty}=0$$
Hence, $$ 0<\frac{2}{1+e^x} < 2 \ \ $$ as desired.

---

Transforming the form of the original form of the function, we get
$$f(x) = \frac{2e^x}{1+e^x} = 2 - \color{blue}{\frac{2}{1+e^x}}$$
where the blue expression has been just discussed. Due to the *little lemma* above,
$$2-\color{blue}2<2 - \color{blue}{\frac{2}{1+e^x}} < 2-\color{blue}0 \\[3pt] 0 < f(x) < 2$$
So, $\text{range}(f) = (0,2)$ and the domain is obviously $\mathbb{R}$.

---

For the inverse function, the domain is $(0,2)$ and the range is $\mathbb{R}$ (just [swap](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=MathApps/DomainAndRangeOfTheInverseFunction) the domain and the range of the original function)

---

Here is the graph to illustrate this:

[image]

Comment: I appreciate the help, could you explain in. a bit more detail how you found the range of F(x)? Many thanks

Comment: @ThomasHegarty See the edit.